# Use <a> or <div> for the image buttons

Tags: html, web

Which way is better for making image buttons?

Using `<a>`:
set background image to my image
have to specify `<a href="#">`, however, there will be a url in browser status bar, which is a bit annoying.

Using `<div>`:
set background image to my image
no url shows in browser status bar, however, have to add `cursor:pointer` in .css

Comment: not following what you mean by 'set background image to my image'? do you mean link?

Comment: @cmwright - I think it's meant in the context of 'set the background image to _be_ my image'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't go for a div personally, because semantically a *div is not a button*. If you want a button that performs a JavaScript action, I'd probably just use the `<button></button>` tag. You can place other HTML elements inside a button tag as you would a div, and it's better semantically.

To reiterate what @Richard JP Le Guen said, ideally you'd add these buttons using JavaScript too, so that people without JavaScript enabled will not see them, or you can offer an alternative functionality for those without JS enabled.

Comment: Good call on the button element. Drop the first paragraph and you got a +1 ;)

Comment: @Richard - Fair enough. I've removed, but not for the rep, I shouldn't be encouraging bad practice. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `<a>` because the browser natively handles the click events.  A clickable `<div>` would require javascript to handle click events.

Showing the destination url in the status bar is normally considered a good design practice.  It gives the user added information where that button/link will take them.

Comment: But <a> as a button requires javascript too!

Comment: @Webars in what world do a tags need javascript to function?

Comment: @Chris - Normally none, but in the question, the functionality is JS based, so JS is required for correct functioning. Using anchors in this case is a bad idea since people with JS disabled might be lead to believe that the links still work for , when it won't.

Comment: If <a> is used as a button to go to a registration page, for example, you are right then - there's no such world. In all other cases - we use javascript.

Comment: @karl-nicoll The question does not state anything about JS or that JS is required to make this image button work.

Comment: @Phil - It's implied from the fact that he was alternatively considering using a `<div>` for the button, which offers no clickable functionality other than through JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Use the second technique; anchors (`<a>`) are for hyperlinks. Using an anchor for dynamic behavior affects the browser status bar (like you said) and also gives users without JavaScript the impression they can interact with the element - which they can't.

Ideally you'd also add this `<div>` using JavaScript, so that users with no JavaScript don't have to see it at all.

Comment: -1, "anchors (<a>) are for hyperlinks" falsely implies anchors have no other uses and are synonmous with hyperlinks, which is in fact not true. You can have an anchor with just a name attribute to create a "bookmark" on the page.

Comment: C'mon @Greg, let's try to contain out [pettiness to one question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096820/html-tag-inside-javascript/7096862) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Stan! There're CSS files with thousands lines of code. That's why one more rule "cursor:pointer" is not a big problem. :)