# HTML tag inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use some HTML tag inside JavaScript, but the HTML tag does not work. How can U use an HTML tag inside JavaScript? I wanted to use `h1` but did not work.

```js
if (document.getElementById('number1').checked) {
  <h1>Hello member</h1>
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: I just want to use less javascript and more Html. I dont know a lot abou javascript.

Answer (score 12):

You will either have to `document.write` it or use the Document Object Model:

## Example using [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.write)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.getElementById('number1').checked) {
    document.write("<h1>Hello member</h1>");
}
</script>
```

## Example using [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM)

```
<h1></h1> <!-- We are targeting this tag with JS. See code below -->
<input type="checkbox" id="number1" checked /><label for="number1">Agree</label>
<div id="container"> <p>Content</p> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    if( document.getElementById('number1').checked ) {
        var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
        h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello member"));
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(h1);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: So that, you are saying that I cannot use tag inside Javascript, instead I should find equivalent method of Javascript?

Comment: -1, missing parenthesis in the DOM example on the var h1 line. Also this example is useless because it doesn't relate to the check

Comment: @user899043: Exactly; tags can't go directly in JavaScript code.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen I'm wondering how React.js is able to do this. No quotes around HTML code. https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/oWWQNa?editors=0010

Comment: I also would like to know how react can use a JavaScript 'return' to return raw HTML code. No one knows?

Comment: It is apparently a new language called JSX: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html . I imagine it only works with react.

Comment: Actually, JSX can be used even without React: https://medium.com/@bluepnume/jsx-is-a-stellar-invention-even-with-react-out-of-the-picture-c597187134b7 / https://itnext.io/lessons-learned-using-jsx-without-react-bbddb6c28561

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
 <body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="number1" onclick="number1();">Number 1</br>
  <p id="h1"></p>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function number1() {
    if(document.getElementById('number1').checked) {

      document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = "<h1>Hello member</h1>";
         }
    }
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used for my countdown clock:

```
</SCRIPT>
<center class="auto-style19" style="height: 31px">
<Font face="blacksmith" size="large"><strong>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var header = "You have <I><font color=red>" 
+ getDaysUntilICD10() + "</font></I>&nbsp; "
header += "days until ICD-10 starts!"
document.write(header)
</SCRIPT>
```

The HTML inside of my script worked, though I could not explain why.

Answer (score 1):

here's how to incorporate variables and html tags in document.write
also note how you can simply add text between the quotes

```
document.write("<h1>System Paltform: ", navigator.platform, "</h1>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="demo"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.getElementById('number1').checked) {
        var demo = document.getElementById("demo");    
        demo.innerHtml='<h1>Hello member</h1>';
    } else {
        demo.innerHtml='';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a scripting language, not a HTMLanguage type. It is mainly to do process at background and it needs `document.write` to display things on browser. 
Also if your `document.write` exceeds one line, make sure to put concatenation `+` at the end of each line.

Example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.getElementById('number1').checked) {
document.write("<h1>Hello" +
"member</h1>");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="demo"></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return empty()">


<script type="text/javascript">
        function empty()
        {
          var x;
          x = document.getElementById("feedbackpost").value;
          if (x == "")
           {
             var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
             demo.innerHTML =document.write='<h1>Hello member</h1>';
              return false;
           };
        }
    </script>
```