# How To Use HtmlTags Inside Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i am stuck on adding some text img and links in my modal code .

the heading tags `<h1 </h1>` are working fine but when i am trying to add link by using `<a> </a>` Tags it is not working `<img> </img>` tags are also not working below is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Delayed modal demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jackmoore/colorbox/master/example1/colorbox.css" />
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jackmoore/colorbox/master/jquery.colorbox- 
min.js"></script>

<script>
  <!-- Code here -->
  setTimeout(function(){
$.colorbox({
html:"How to Add Link and img here    ",
className: "cta",
width: 350,
height: 150
});
}, 1000);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html tag inside javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096820/html-tag-inside-javascript)

Comment: try looking a jquery https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the doc, Colorbox accepts html.
Either use this syntax :

`html:"How to Add <a href='https://google.com'>Link</a> and img <img src='http://www.jacklmoore.com/img/jackmoore.jpg' /> here    ",`

or escaping quotes :

`html:"How to Add <a href=\"https://google.com\">Link</a> and img <img src=\"http://www.jacklmoore.com/img/jackmoore.jpg\" /> here    ",`

Here is a working example below:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Delayed modal demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jackmoore/colorbox/master/example1/colorbox.css" />
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.6.4/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

<script>
  <!-- Code here -->
  setTimeout(function(){
    $.colorbox({
    html:"How to Add <a href='https://google.com'>Link</a> and img <img src='http://www.jacklmoore.com/img/jackmoore.jpg' /> here    ",
    className: "cta",
    width: 350,
    height: 150
    });
  }, 1000);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.colorbox({
        html:"<a href=''><img src='image.jpg'></a>",
        className: "cta",
        width: 350,
        height: 150
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: aint working , btw someone give me a correct answer above :)