# Enter a value in a "text/html" script via another script

Tags: javascript

Maybe this is a naive question but I wonder if there is a way to enter a value in a "text/html" script via another script, something like the following example which, by the way, does not work for me.

```
<script id="Block" type="text/html">
<input type="text" id="InputID"/>
</script>

<script>
document.getElementById('InputID').value = 'some text';
</script>
```

Comment: It works if you don't wrap your HTML in a script tag needlessly.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve placing HTML inside a script tag with type as html? Just curious

Comment: [More on HTML "scripts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883553/what-are-modern-uses-of-script-type-text-html-and-is-this-example-considered-g)

Comment: @ Josh Bonnick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096820/html-tag-inside-javascript

Comment: To what in that lengthy page are you referring us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `type` of a `<script>` element to `text/html` is a hack for including some HTML source code in an HTML document without it being rendered so that you can later read the script element and do something with the HTML source code.

```
const raw_html = document.querySelector("script[type='text/html']").textContent;
```

This works because normal HTML rules do not apply to a script element, `<` has no special meaning there (in HTML 4 terms, the script element contains CDATA).

The modern equivalent is [the `<template>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

You have no `<input>` element, so you can't find it in the DOM and you can't set a value to it.

If you want to do that, you first need to add it to the DOM.

```js
const raw_html = document.querySelector("script[type='text/html']").textContent;
const container = document.querySelector("#container");
container.innerHTML = raw_html;
document.getElementById('InputID').value = 'some text';
```

```html
<script id="Block" type="text/html">
<input type="text" id="InputID"/>
</script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: A big bravo Quentin !!! Very clear and surprisingly so quick as an answer !!! Thank you a lot